# Add a custom fee to totals block of invoice/order email

Tags: totals, order-email

So far I could add a custom fee to an order. It shows on checkout page, admin order view, admin invoice view, invoice pdf. But I don't know how I should do to display it in order/invoice email.

[image]

I see one way to do this is: override `_initTotals` method of `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals` class. But I don't know if this will affect another places, or if other extension wants to do the same thing (adding some custom fees to the totals block), then they will conflict.

I doubted that there's a way to add a total to totals block via xml, or binding to some event...

Given the fact that there's a column called `customfee_total` in `sales_flat_order` table, what's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

Add the following code to your module `config.xml`

```
<config>
...
   <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customfee>
                    <file>customfee.xml</file>
                </customfee>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
...
</config>
```

add `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customfee.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <sales_email_order_items>
        <reference name="order_totals">
            <block type="customfee/sales_totals_order_customfee" name="customfee"/>
        </reference>
    </sales_email_order_items>

    <sales_email_order_invoice_items>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="customfee/sales_totals_order_invoice_customfee" name="customfee"/>
        </reference>
    </sales_email_order_invoice_items>

    <sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
        <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
            <block type="customfee/sales_totals_order_creditmemo_customfee" name="customfee"/>
        </reference>
    </sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
</layout>
```

Example `app/code/local/Cream/CustomFee/Block/Sales/Totals/Order/Customfee.php`

```
class Cream_CustomFee_Block_Sales_Totals_Order_Customfee extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
  public function initTotals() {

    if((float) $this->getParentBlock()->getSource()->getCustomfeeTotal() == 0) {
      return $this;
    }

    $total = new Varien_Object(array(
      'code'  => $this->getNameInLayout(),
      'value' => $this->getParentBlock()->getSource()->getCustomfeeTotal(),
      'label' => Mage::helper('customfee')->getName()
    ));

    $after = 'subtotal';

    $this->getParentBlock()->addTotal($total, $after);
    return $this;
  }
}
```

Comment: How solve it for Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

follow this [tutorial](http://astrio.net/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/)

you have to `override sales_order_invoice_totals`

```
<global>
     <sales>

         <order_invoice>
             <totals>
                 <turnkeye_insurance>
                     <class>turnkeye_insurance/total_screen_invoice</class>
                     <after>subtotal</after>
                     <before>tax</before>
                 </turnkeye_insurance>
             </totals>
         </order_invoice>

     </sales>
 </global> 




class Turnkeye_Insurance_Model_Total_Screen_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        $amount = INSURANCE_FEE; //add your fee here
        if ($amount) {
            $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() + $amount);
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() + $amount);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but this is not the right answer, this only adds a row to invoice totals (admin order view), not the email

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm this is also add row in invoice total.

Comment: @QaisarSatti could you pls help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/212197/57334