# Add a discount row on order total in backend order view

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a new row which will contain a label of **Discount** and a value of that label.

Please see the screenshot

[image]

Any idea or any link about how to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add  by rewriting `Sales_Order_Totals` block

```
<adminhtml>
        <rewrite><sales_order_totals>Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals</sales_order_totals>
        </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

rewrite file path

```
<?php
class Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals
{
    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $order_id=$this->getOrder()->getId(); 




           $amount=5; 

        if ($amount) {
            $this->addTotalBefore(new Varien_Object(array(
                'code'      => 'fee',
                'value'     => $amount,
                'base_value'=> $amount,
                'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Fee'),
            ), array('shipping', 'tax')));
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nV8zt.png    *This is what i get after adding your code*

Comment: i use this code for displaying the custom fee.. try it..

Comment: Sorry there was some problem on creating class. But when i solve that it giving me **Warning: include(Mage\Sale\Helper\Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory** tis error. any idea??

Comment: update the code try it and feedback...

Comment: @QaisarSatti How can i add Discount for Order Total?

Comment: @zus follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97133/add-a-custom-fee-to-totals-block-of-invoice-order-email